# What would happen if i created an entity instance using new operator and set its id(PK) manually and then try to persist it(calling EM#persist())?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

What would happen if i created an entity instance using new operator and set its id(PK) manually and then try to persist it(calling EntityManager#persist())?

please can you elaborate more on the entity states?

Comment: Why do not you try it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: I have tried this and getting an error: trying to persist a detached entity and i am not able to understand why jpa is throwing this error, it's not a detached entity

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about manually assigning primary key for entities. If you call persist, it will go into the managed entity state. At the end of the transaction, an `INSERT` query will be executed (if you haven't flushed the `EntityManager` before that manually).

I'd recommend reading [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) article to make it more clear.

Comment: I have tried this and getting an error: trying to persist a detached entity and i am not able to understand why jpa is throwing this error, it's not a detached entity

Comment: Sounds like you tried to persist an entity which was retrieved from the DB rather than a new instance.

Comment: Actually the scenario is of REST service when I am trying to send a json(having entity id) and calling persist on de-serialised object it is throwing trying to persist a detach entity.